# Create a button for every file in a directory in html

Tags: php, html

I'm new to html and php. The following code creates visible links to the files in the directory 'mydirectory'. But how can I create a button for each file, so when they click a particular button, the file that corresponds to it will open?

```
<?php
$handle = opendir('mydirectory');

if($handle){
    while(($entry = readdir($handle)) !== false){
        if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && $entry != '.htaccess'){
          echo "<font color='red'><a href=\"mydirectory/$entry\"          style='color:#f9c539' >$entry</a><br></font>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the 'a' tag by a 'button' tag. And instead of using the 'href' attribute, you need to execute some JavaScript on the click event.

```
<?php
$handle = opendir('mydirectory');

if($handle){
    while(($entry = readdir($handle)) !== false){
        if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && $entry != '.htaccess'){
          echo "<button onclick=\"location.href='mydirectory/$entry'\">$entry</button><br>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed. How can I set the size of the buttons?

Comment: You will need to learn one more language: [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

Comment: Thank You rcpinto. Just one final question. How can I organize the buttons in rows and columns? lets say, 4 rows, 3 columns?

Comment: For now, use html tables (table, tr and td tags). When you have time, learn to do it with CSS, which is most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but for future readers, you can stick with the "a" tag and simply use css to style it to look like a button. This is also where you would add things like padding and margins, but I included a short example with just the basics to look like a button. This would (often) be stored in a seperate css file, which you can link into your html file.

```css
a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #131069; 
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #818181;
}
```